# What does error SRVE0315E indicate in ibm websphere liberty server?

Tags: websphere, websphere-liberty, websphere-commerce

I have WebSphere application server liberty - **17.0.0.2** installed. When i try to hit website URL after turning up crsServer, The front page displays "*An error has occurred. Please contact your system administrator*" message.

Initially everything was working fine but suddenly the storeFront stopped showing and there is below error printed in console.

```
SRVE0315E: An exception occurred: java.lang.Throwable: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Here are the logs

```
[1/16/23 19:50:48:986 IST] 00000020 com.ibm.commerce.foundation.logging.ExtendedInfo             I CWXFR9010I: Extended information : [URL=http://appsrv-05.kotsovolos.gr:8080/webapp/remote/preview/] [parameters=null] [userId=-1002] 
[1/16/23 19:50:49:018 IST] 00000020 com.ibm.ws.logging.internal.impl.IncidentImpl                I FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created: "javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter 144" at ffdc_23.01.16_19.50.48.0.log
[1/16/23 19:50:49:049 IST] 00000020 com.ibm.ws.logging.internal.impl.IncidentImpl                I FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created: "javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter 82" at ffdc_23.01.16_19.50.49.0.log
[1/16/23 19:50:49:064 IST] 00000020 com.ibm.ws.logging.internal.impl.IncidentImpl                I FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created: "javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters 1064" at ffdc_23.01.16_19.50.49.1.log
[1/16/23 19:50:49:064 IST] 00000020 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp                               E SRVE0315E: An exception occurred: java.lang.Throwable: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:5027)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer31.osgi.webapp.WebApp31.handleRequest(WebApp31.java:528)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.handleRequest(DynamicVirtualHost.java:315)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1025)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:280)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:967)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.wrapHandlerAndExecute(HttpDispatcherLink.java:359)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.ready(HttpDispatcherLink.java:318)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:471)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:405)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:285)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:256)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:174)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:83)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java:504)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java:574)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java:929)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java:1018)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1153)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:785)
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ibm.commerce.store.servlet.StoreRuntimeServletFilter.doFilter(StoreRuntimeServletFilter.java:529)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:207)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.ibm.commerce.store.preview.servlet.PreviewFilter.doFilter(PreviewFilter.java:97)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:207)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.ibm.commerce.cf.servlet.ExecutionContextFilter.doFilter(ExecutionContextFilter.java:311)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:207)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:1021)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1143)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4983)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ibm.commerce.store.servlet.StoreRuntimeServletFilter.doFilterAction(StoreRuntimeServletFilter.java:636)
    at com.ibm.commerce.store.servlet.StoreRuntimeServletFilter$1.run(StoreRuntimeServletFilter.java:410)
    at com.ibm.commerce.store.servlet.StoreRuntimeServletFilter.doFilter(StoreRuntimeServletFilter.java:433)
    ... 31 more
```

I am trying to solve this error but i am not able to find root cause. even in the official documentations i am not able to find information on **SRVE0315E**. can anyone guide me what can be issue??

Answer (score 2):

It means that an exception was thrown when trying to call a servlet. In this case the exception is a NullPointerException thrown from a Servlet Filter. The exception stack in your question indicates exactly where this occurred:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ibm.commerce.store.servlet.StoreRuntimeServletFilter.doFilterAction(StoreRuntimeServletFilter.java:636)
    at com.ibm.commerce.store.servlet.StoreRuntimeServletFilter$1.run(StoreRuntimeServletFilter.java:410)
    at com.ibm.commerce.store.servlet.StoreRuntimeServletFilter.doFilter(StoreRuntimeServletFilter.java:433)
```

The `com.ibm.commerce.store.servlet.StoreRuntimeServletFilter` class is not a Liberty class and the source is not in the question so I cannot comment on what caused it to throw a NullPointerException, but you would need to either look to the source of that class, or contact the owner of it for more information on why this occurred.